# table doens't show the updated column

Tags: php, html, mysqli

in my code, the table doesn't refresh and show the updated column once the update button is clicked.

[image]

here is my code.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $Project = $_POST['Project'];
    $No = $_POST['No'];
    $SubID = $_POST['SubID'];
    $RequestAmount = $_POST['RequestAmount'];
    $PaidAmount = $_POST['PaidAmount'];
    $AmountToPay = $_POST['AmountToPay'];
    $State = $_POST['State'];

    //UPDATE Query of SQL
    $sql = "UPDATE memo SET Project='$Project',No='$No',SubID='$SubID',RequestAmount='$RequestAmount',PaidAmount='$PaidAmount',AmountToPay='$AmountToPay',State='$State' WHERE No='$No' AND SubID='$SubID'"
            or die("Failed to query database" .mysqli_error());
    $result = $link->query($sql); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Using Ajax to refresh the table content..

Comment: you definitely need to implement client-side programming here. PHP is server side.

Comment: The code you have doesn’t do anything else but perform an update in the database. Why would you expect that this would change your current, existing HTML in any way on its own …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you update database after loading the page.

You can do something like that:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $Project = $_POST['Project'];
        $No = $_POST['No'];
        $SubID = $_POST['SubID'];
        $RequestAmount = $_POST['RequestAmount'];
        $PaidAmount = $_POST['PaidAmount'];
        $AmountToPay = $_POST['AmountToPay'];
        $State = $_POST['State'];

        //UPDATE Query of SQL
        $sql = "UPDATE memo SET Project='$Project',No='$No',SubID='$SubID',RequestAmount='$RequestAmount',PaidAmount='$PaidAmount',AmountToPay='$AmountToPay',State='$State' WHERE No='$No' AND SubID='$SubID'"
        or die("Failed to query database" .mysqli_error());
        $result = $link->query($sql);
        header("Refresh: 0;");
        die();
    }
?>
```

I added lines

```
header("Refresh: 0;");
die();
```

It simply refreshes the page after update.
Hope this helps, if not, then sorry.